# Split image file in two separate image

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

I have on my server an image file with an height of 50 000px.
I want to save 2 files of 25 000px each (first and second part of the original image)

Any suggestions about how to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sharp image package might be useful for this scenario. More specifically the [extract method](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-resize#extract).

I've added a link to the documentation but here's a possible implementation to split up the image.

```js
const sharp = require("sharp");

const originalFilename = "image.jpg";


const image = sharp(originalFilename);

// this is just a placeholder
const imageWidth = 500;

image
  .extract({ left: 0, top: 0, width: imageWidth, height: 25000 })
  .toFile("top.jpg", function(err) {
    // Save the top of the image to a file named "top.jpg"
  });

image
  .extract({ left: 0, top: 25000, width: imageWidth, height: 25000 })
  .toFile("bottom.jpg", function(err) {
    // Save the bottom of the image to a file named "bottom.jpg"
  });
```

I'm assuming you can reuse the original sharp image object to call the extract function twice. If not you might need to call the sharp constructor again.

Comment: It works, and it's exactly what I needed. Thanks !